# Duplicate entry error with multiple request at exact same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm doing a test on my code it's working on single request without a problem but when I've tried sending it on multiple requests at the same time I'm having a duplicate error. I'm using MySQL as database.

Model

```
class Playtime < ApplicationRecord
  validates :local_id, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true
end
```

Controller

From this

```
def create
    begin
      if !Playtime.where(local_id: params[:local_id]).exists?
        @playtime = Playtime.create!(playtime_params)
        json_response(@playtime.local_id,true)
      else
        json_response(params[:local_id], true)
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
      json_response(invalid.record.errors.full_messages.first,false)
    end
  end
```

To this, I thought it will be fixed with this.

```
def create
    begin
      if !Playtime.where(local_id: params[:local_id]).exists?
        @playtime = Playtime.create(playtime_params)
        if @playtime.valid?
          json_response(@playtime.local_id,true)
        else
          json_response(params[:local_id], true)
        end
      else
        json_response(params[:local_id], true)
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
      json_response(invalid.record.errors.full_messages.first,false)
    end
  end
```

But same error.

My request.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/events/playtime \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: b4a636e9-5802-446f-9770-692895ebdbfd' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "local_id": "664278-153"
}'&
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/events/playtime \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: b4a636e9-5802-446f-9770-692895ebdbfd' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "local_id": "664278-153"
}'
```

Error without passing on rescue.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '664278-153' for key 'index_playtimes_on_local_id': INSERT INTO `playtimes`
```

Comment: What's the error it raises without the rescue?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Sorry edited on last part.

Comment: Try replacing `create` with `new` before invoking `valid?`, what do you get?

Comment: Same error for replacing `create` to `new` `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '664278-153' for key 'index_playtimes_on_local_id': INSERT INTO `playtimes``

Comment: May I ask why are you using a single "&" for the curl requests? When I do the same, I'm seeing twice the logs of my debugger. When I use "&&" everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, that's the case I'm looking for. It seems like when I use "&&" there's a slight delay on each request but the problem is their mobile application is sending multiple requests without delay like using "&" on curl.

Comment: Well, you're rescuing RecordInvalid but receiving RecordNotUnique ... maybe just rescue both errors? You can rescue multiple errors in the same line e.g. `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if !Playtime.where(local_id: params[:local_id]).exists?
  # ⇒ SWITCH OF THE CONTEXT, RECORD CREATED BY ANOTHER PROCESS
  @playtime = Playtime.create!(playtime_params)
```

Basically, the check passes and then *before* create gets to the database the other process that handled the simultaneous request *has created the record* in the database.

The most common railish approach would be to use [Optimistic Locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) and rescue [StaleObjectError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962492/ruby-on-rails-what-is-stale-object-and-its-features), but here you already have a constraint on the field, so it’d be even easier:

```
def create
  # no need to begin here, you might rescue the whole function body
  @playtime = Playtime.create!(playtime_params)
  json_response(@playtime.local_id, true)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    # record is already there, ok
    json_response(params[:local_id], true)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    # params are invalid, report
    json_response(invalid.record.errors.full_messages.first, false)
end
```

*Sidenote:* we usually supply an HTTP error code with error reporting, your code currently likely serves `200 OK` within “invalid” response.

Comment: This really helps! Thank you! I'm getting an error `syntax error, unexpected =>"` but ive fixed it by adding `rescue` on each like this : `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => _error` and `rescue  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid` Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed, sorry, fixed.

Comment: and also I've removed this: `validates :local_id, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true` to model because with that I'm getting local_id is already taken. By removing that it will just display the current local_id. Thank you!